# API testing: How do I mock/patch a method in one place only?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, tornado

I am trying to patch/mock a method (`AsyncHTTPClient.fetch`) that is being called in two different places in my program: Firstly in `tornado_openapi3.testing` and secondly in `my_file`. The problem is that the method is being patched in the first location, which breaks the functionality of my tests.

my_file.py:

```
import tornado
class Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler, ABC):
    def initialize(self):
        <some_code>
    
    async def get(self, id):
        <some_code>
        client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        response = await client.fetch(<some_path>)
        <some_code>
```

test_handler.py:

```
from tornado_openapi3.testing import AsyncOpenAPITestCase



class HandlerTestCase(AsyncOpenAPITestCase):
    def get_app(self) -> Application:
        return <some_app>
    
    def test_my_handler(self): 
        with patch.object(my_file.AsyncHTTPClient, 'fetch') as mock_fetch:
            f = asyncio.Future()
            f.set_result('some_result_for_testing')
            mock_fetch.return_value = f
            self.fetch(<some_path>)
```

From what I understood from various mocking tutorials (e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html), `fetch` should only be patched/mocked in `my_file`. How can I make sure that is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Cause of the issue

The imported class `AsyncHTTPClient` in `my_file.py` is actually just a reference to tornado's original `AsyncHTTPClient` class.

Basically, `from x import y` statements are variable assignments in that a new variable called `y` is created in the current file referencing the original object `x.y`.

And, since, classes are mutable objects, when you patch the `fetch` method in the imported class, you are actually patching the `fetch` method on the original class.

Here's an example using variable assignment to illustrate this issue:

```py
class A:
    x = 1

b = A # create a variable 'b' referencing the class 'A'

b.x = 2 # change the value of 'x' attribute' of 'b'

print(A.x)
# Outputs -> 2 (not 1 because classes are mutable)
```

Like I said earlier, `from ... import ...` statements are basically variable assignments. So the above illustration is what's really happening when you patch the `fetch` method.

---

#### Solution

Instead of patching a single method, patch the **whole class**:

```py
with patch.object(my_file, 'AsyncHTTPClient') as mock_client:
    f = asyncio.Future()
    f.set_result('some_result_for_testing')

    mock_client.fetch.return_value = f

    self.fetch(<some_path>)
```

What's happening this time is Python is reassigning the value of the local variable `AsyncHTTPClient` to a mock object. There's no *mutation* going on this time and, so, the original class is not affected.